# Why are diorite, andesite, and granite not spawning in All the Mods 6?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

[All the Mods 6 is a modpack for Minecraft 1.16](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/all-the-mods-6).

I spent a long time mining and exploring caves but I haven't found any andesite, granite, or diorite. Andesite and granite are my favorite building blocks, and andesite is also used in the Create mod.

Andesite, granite, and diorite are not spawning anywhere. Is this intentional? Do I have to craft them with cobblestone and nether quartz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quark](http://vazkii.net/subdom/quark/#features) has a module called Big Stone Clusters that changes how these blocks generate:

[image]

**Solution 1: Change the config**

To change this behavior, navigate to your config folder and open quark-common.toml. Set "Big Stone Clusters" = false at the following line:

```
[world]
    "Big Dungeon" = true
    "Big Stone Clusters" = false
    Biotite = true
    "Blossom Trees" = true
```

I installed All the Mods 6 and tested this for you; with the module disabled (as above), I found small patches of all three stone types in the biome I started in (Crag Gardens). I haven't tested other biomes.

**Solution 2: Look in these biomes**

Alternatively, if you want to find these blocks without changing anything, the Quark website outlines [how they are generated](http://vazkii.net/subdom/quark/#features) (navigate to the World tab):

- Granite will spawn in Mountain and Hill biomes.
- Diorite will spawn in Savanna, Jungle, and Mushroom biomes.
- Andesite will spawn in Forest
  biomes.

Note that they will be in larger, less frequent veins.